# mongodb with PHP driver aggregate(find) with multiple $match $or $and condition

Tags: php, mongodb

hi i have a problom with mongo $aggregate on the php driver
i have this code in PHP:

```
$match1 = array( '$and' => array(
    array("uid" => array('$nin'=> $where_blocked)),
    array("type" => "picture" ),
    array("active" => true )
));

$match2 = array( '$and' => array(
    array("uid" => array('$in'=> $where)),
    array("type" => "users" )
));

$query = array(
    array(
        '$match' => array(
            '$or' => array( $match1,$match2 )
        ),
    ),
    array(
        '$lookup' => array(
            'from' => 'users',
            'localField' => 'objId',
            'foreignField' => '_id',
            'as' => 'user'
        ),
    ),
    array(
        '$lookup' => array(
            'from' => 'pictures',
            'localField' => 'objId',
            'foreignField' => '_id',
            'as' => 'pic'
        ),
    ),

    array(
        '$limit' => $pageSize
    ),
    array(  
        '$sort' => array("DateCreated" => -1 )
    ),
    array(
        '$skip' => $pageSize*($page-1)
    )
);

$cursor = $log->aggregate($query);
```

this is working but i only get the `$match1` not the `$match2` i need to get OR match 1 or match2 depending of the most new document.
on find this wil work:

```
$query_or = array('$or' => array($match1,$match2));
$cursor = $log->find($query_or)->sort(array("DateCreated" => -1))->skip($pageSize*($page-1))->limit($pageSize);
```

but need the `$lookup` (join) and i can not use it on `find`
can someone help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you absolutely need to use $lookup, just use aggregate instead of find.
It does work and will bring you all the data:

```
db.your_table.aggregate([
    { 
        $match: { 
            $or: [
                {type:"picture"}, 
                {type:"rate"} 
            ]                   
        } 
    },
    { 
        $lookup: { 
            'from' : 'users',
            'localField' : 'objId',
            'foreignField' : '_id',
            'as' :'user'
        } 
    },
    { 
        $lookup: { 
            'from' : 'pictures',
            'localField' : 'objId',
            'foreignField' : '_id',
            'as': 'pic'
        } 
    }
])
```